# How to distinguish whether the class files in the jar package belong to itself or its dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm working on some jars and building call graphs by analyzing bytecode files. I only want to analyze the class files belonging to the jar package itself, not its dependencies

The Maven central repository does not stipulate that the uploaded jar package must have its dependencies or not, and the class files in the jar package are not always organized according to groupId and artifactId.

For example, I download *antisamy-1.5.3.jar* from [Maven Central Repository] (https://search.maven.org/). And its id is *org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.5.3*. The following figure is the directory organization structure of this jar package.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USacO.png)
We can see that the path where the class file is located is not prefixed with groupId and artifactId.

There is an another expamle called *org.apache.sling.xss-2.0.0.jar* with the id *org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.xss:2.0.0*.It looks like this jar package contains many class files from its dependencies.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3zsy.png)

Did anyone know how to distinguish them from its dependency class files?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This part: `does not stipulate that the uploaded jar package must have its dependencies or not,` I don't understand. Of course does a jar not contain it's dependencies it's expressed by the givem pom file with the defined dependencies... ? The second example is an OSGi bundle... and contains the defined OSGi dependencies... The pom file of it tells the packaging type: `bundle`?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your comment! Actually I am not familar with Maven. I find that when there is  no **<packaging>** in a pom file or it is **bundle**, the jar file may contains many class files not belonging itself:
'org.apache.tika:tika-server:1.17', 'org.apache.jackrabbit:oak-run:1.8.0', 'org.apache.tika:tika-app:1.17'...

I only want to deal with the class files compiled from the source code of the package itself, and don't want any other dependencies. Could you please tell me how to make that?

Comment: If there is no packaging it means the default is `jar`.. `the jar file may contains many class files not belonging itself: org.apache.tika:tika-server:1.17` ? What do you mean by `not belonging itself`? can you enhance your post by a concrete example?

Comment: I download the jar [org.apache.tika:tika-server:1.17](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.17/tika-server-1.17.jar). I think only the class files in **/org/apache/tika/server/** belong to this package. But there are many other directories and class files.

I am wondering if it is always possible to tell the internal and external classes apart

Answer (score 0):

"Normal" libraries don't contain their dependencies.

But there are exceptions, like OSGi bundles or fat JARs. I don't think it is always possible to tell the internal and external classes apart, though in most cases, the Java packages will help you.

Comment: Yeah that's what I found...And I am wondering if it is possible so I asked this question...

Comment: If you asks this for any JAR on MavenCentral, then the answer is probably no. If you analyse a special subset, like the dependencies of a concrete project, you can probably do it by carefully looking at the JARs.

Comment: Generally, you should try to avoid dependencies that contain other dependencies.

Comment: Actually I have many concrete projects and I download jars of them and their dependents on MavenCentral. I want to tell their internal and external classes apart automatically...